# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error - Can't decrypt the encrypted public key

Tags: java, encryption

Here are my encryption settings

```
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
public static final String CIPHER = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
public static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";
public static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withRSA";
public static final int KEY_SIZE = 1048;
```

Here is my code to encrypt

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt, String keyPath){

    int keyLength = KEY_SIZE/8 - 11;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String toEncryptString = new String(toEncrypt,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String[] lines = toEncryptString.split("(?<=\\G.{" + keyLength + "})");

    byte[] encryptedData = new byte[0];

    try{
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath));
        final PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) inputStream.readObject();
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);

        if(toEncrypt.length >= keyLength){
            for(String line : lines){
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(cipher.doFinal(line.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            }
        }else{
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt));
        }
        encryptedData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] cipheredData = base64Encoder(encryptedData);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipheredData));

    return cipheredData;
}
```

Here is my code to decrypt

```
public byte[] decrypt(byte[] toDecrypt, String keyPath) {
    byte[] decypherText = base64Decoder(toDecrypt);

    System.out.println(toDecrypt.length);
    System.out.println(decypherText.length);

    int keyLength = KEY_SIZE/8 - 11; 

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String toEncryptString = Arrays.toString(decypherText);

    String[] lines = toEncryptString.split("(?<=\\G.{" + keyLength + "})");

    byte[] decipheredData = new byte[0];

    try{
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(keyPath));
        final PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) inputStream.readObject();
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKey);

        if(decypherText.length >= keyLength){
            for(String line : lines){
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(cipher.doFinal(line.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            }
        }else{
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(cipher.doFinal(decypherText));
        }
        decipheredData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(decipheredData));

    return decipheredData;
}
```

I'm trying to encrypt a Public Key "A" with the Public Key "B". Encryption is successful, but when I try to decrypt it with the Private Key "B", it gives me that error.

The code looks fine to me, already reviewed it several times, these past 16 hours, already searched through several posts in here, and did not found a suitable answer for my problem.

Also, it already gave me BadPaddingException when decrypting. "Data must not be longer than 131 bytes". However, I'm using a Cipher with padding, so it can only decrypt data with 120 bytes. Why this error, if the Public key ciphered is splitted into blocks of 120 bytes?

Edit: before anyone else says that encrypting a Public Key is a mistery, have in your mind that it's the purpose of the project.. to have a Public Key as an ID and, as such, the need to encrypt so that no one discovers the ID of the user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if `toEncrypt` is a Base64-encoded public key, it will contain binary data after being Base64-decoded which you *cannot* treat as Strings and split them. You would need to split them by working on the `byte[]`. Also, there are other issues with your code, but this seems the first one you should work on.

Comment: So many confusing things in this code...  Why did you pick a key size of 1048 bits?  Why are you encrypting a public key?

Comment: @ArtjomB. So I should split the bytes instead of converting them to String?

Comment: @LukePark it only started to get confusing when I had to encrypt a Public Key. In our project, the Public Key will work as an ID, so since we are communicating between a client-server, we have to encrypt it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense. You're trying to split the ciphertext on a plaintext string. It isn't there. It got removed when you split the string. In any case the data has been encrypted, so searching for a plaintext in it is futile.

You should be base64-decoding, decrypting, reading objects, and then *recombining* them using `"(?<=\\G.{" + keyLength + "})"` as a delimiter.

In fact why you're splitting in the first place and then encrypting multiple lines is a mystery.

And why you're serializing is another. Just encrypt the entire thing, without splitting, base64-encode it, and save that. When decrypting, just base64-decode it and decrypt it.

And, finally, why you're encrypting a public key ***at all*** is a complete mystery. It's **PUBLIC**. Not a secret.

Comment: I wouldn't be encrypting a public key if it wasn't asked.. in the project that was given to us all, we have to send a public key from the client to the server and store it, since the public key will work as an ID of the user. If we had a regular ID, we would want it to not be in plain text, right? Same thing goes with the Public Key.. we must encrypt it. I just can't cypher a large byte[] , that's why I'm splitting the byte[] in smaller blocks, per say. To decrypt, I can't also decrypt the cypher text as a whole, hence splitting it and trying to decrypt.

Comment: A public key is a public entity. If you're trying to use it as an authentication mechanism, you're doing something wrong, and encrypting it doesn't change that. Anybody can encrypt any public key with any other public key. It proves exactly nothing. What you need is something *signed* by the user's *private* key. This may be your assignment, but it is still complete nonsense. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: So you are saying that probably we have to sign it with the user's private Key? My last sentence is that it was giving me the error that the data was too big to decipher, that's why I was trying to split in order to decipher it.

Comment: That's not what I am 'saying', it is what I *said*, and there is no 'probably' about it. Your last sentence didn't say anything about 'too big to decipher'.